# How to set up the directory of an anonymous vsftpd server

Tags: ftp, webserver, vsftp

I have set up a `vsftp` server with anonymous access. `vsftpd.conf` contains the following:

```
anon_root=/var/www/ftp/
secure_chroot_dir=/var/www/ftp
local_root=/var/www/ftp
```

After login in as anonymous, the `ls` command is successful executed but doesn't show any in my files contained in `/var/www/ftp`. I suppose that this is because the ftp root directory is not set properly. Am I correct?

---

```
# cat /etc/vsftpd.conf

listen=NO
listen_ipv6=YES
anonymous_enable=YES
anon_root=/var/www/ftp/
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
chown_uploads=YES
chown_username=root
ascii_upload_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/www/ftp
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO
local_root=/var/www/ftp
```

Comment: What is the distro you're using? Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: I am on Kali 4.6. SELinux is not enabled